# Why value defined in `values.xml` gets overriden?

Tags: android, android-theme

I have clean Android project initialized from AndroidStudio. I am trying to change style of `actionMenuItem` so it is not in uppercase.

I found out that there is an `abc_config_actionMenuItemAllCaps` boolean set in `\appcompat-1.4.1\res\values\values.xml`.

I tried to override it by this `values.xml` file:

```xml
<resources>
    <bool name="abc_config_actionMenuItemAllCaps">false</bool>
</resources>
```

but it does not work.

I am not trying to find a solution for having `actionMenuItem` lowercase. I am trying to get reasoning behind why overriding the boolean is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It's because library gets the value from its values file not from your app's `values.xml`. For instance:
You get some boolean value using:

```
getResources().getBoolean(com.yourapps.package.R.bool.some_id);
```

but library uses:

```
getResources().getBoolean(com.library.package.R.bool.some_id);
```

As you can see paths are different, so it is simply impossible to override in this way.